# FreeCodeCamp CardCounting Can you please correct my code what is wrong..?

Tags: javascript

the card counting rule is attached as below link.
[link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/counting-cards)

And My code is below:

```
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if ([2,3,4,5,6].includes(card)){
    count++;
  } else if (   [10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'].includes(card)) {
    count--;
  } else {
  card = 0;
  count = count;
  }
  return count>0?card+" Bet":card+" Hold"
  // Only change code above this line
}
```

Can you please correct me why my code is wrong.. Thank you for any feedback!

I tried using if else statement and use includes method.. but I guess the logic required is not right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided the wrong variable.

> The function will then return a string with the current count and the string Bet if the count is positive .....

replace **card** with **count** variable.

```
return count > 0 ? count +" Bet" : count +" Hold"
```

Comment: Thank you.. I was wondering why it was not working..

Answer (score 1):

There's a little mistake on your **return**. Instead of returning:

```
return count>0?card+" Bet":card+" Hold"
```

You should replace all *card* with *count*:

```
return count>0?count+" Bet":count+" Hold"
```